# unity3d - changing FPSInputController controls through script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, user-controls, user-input, keymapping

I asked this question on unity answers a while back but it is still waiting for "approval by a moderator", so I posted it here:

For a game I am making I would like the user to be able to change the controls (in game NOT through the clunky launch window (which I disabled)). I have the system working, but I don't know how to change the controls for FPS controller. I am okay with writing my own version of the FPSInputController but I don't really know how to do that (the good way (using the CharcaterMotor)). I looked at the original FPSInputController script, but that used axis (from the "conventional" input settings in unity) and I don't really know how to do that with:

```
if (Input.GetKey(controls.forward))
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The user can already change the controls in you game, you don't have to worry about it. There's a special dialog at the start, that user is presented with unless you disabled it:

[image: Unity launch dialog]

You can read more about input how user can configure input buttons in [the manual](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ConventionalGameInput.html).

Comment: Yes, I know but as stated in my question I don't want to use the launch dialog. I think it's clunky and unprofessional.

Comment: I'm sorry for not reading your question carefully. No, it's not possible right now without writing your own input manager. You can vote for this feature [here](http://feedback.unity3d.com/suggestions/scripting-expose-input-manager-).